# What is the grammatical structure after the comma?

Tags: commas, comparisons

> Even with the proposed budget cuts and new taxes and fees, the city's projected deficit for the next budget year is getting worse: administration officials announced that they believe the gap will be $3.7 billion, a billion dollars **more than they had predicted** just two months ago.

What is the grammatical structure after the comma (a billion dollars more than... )? I thought it was an appositive but "a billion dollars.." is not really restating another noun. Is it an adjective phrase?

Comment: One could argue that it's a "parenthetical".

Comment: It's an appositive. *$3.7 billion* = *3.7 billion dollars*. Nouns, both. *A billion dollars...* is also a noun. Cf. *He was a cat, a cat in a hat.*

Answer (score 1):

This could be an instance of **ellipsis**:

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis)
the omission of one or more words that are obviously understood but that must be supplied to make a construction grammatically complete

The complete version of the clause would have been:

the gap will be $3.7 billion, [which is] a billion dollars more than they had predicted just two months ago.

[which is] was [elided] omitted to make the sentence more compact.

Comment: Elision is the great illusion of grammarians.

Comment: Wrong term. Edited to 'omitted' :)

Comment: Thanks! The answer makes total sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

My reflex is that your instinct on it being an adjective phrase is too straighforward to be false. It is an adjective phrase modifying the noun "$3.7 billion."

I do not think there are any absent or implied words. The fact that words can be sensibly inserted does not mean they are necessary, directly or by implication. I think there are probably a lot of adjective phrases that could absorb some additional connective tissue without gaining much weight, but that makes no imperative to increase their diet.

I am not a grammarian and am wrong with shocking frequency.